# What event should I use in a User Control on a form refresh/requisition on Genexus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, genexus

Whenever I need to make an ajax request to the server without refreshing the page, Genexus should emit some event that I could use in my UC.

What exactly would be this event, and if there is none, how could I know every events in JS to use in an Genexus User Control?

I.e.:
If I click in an UserAction that may search for values in another table and then retrieve then for me, how can I capture this?

Another Scenario:

I'm making a request to the server and retrieving information of it. I need to get the
   `$(gx-warning-message).text();`
but if my request is still loading, when I execute my function, it will return nothing, because the event is still loading up informations.

To avoid this, I'm making a looping, but it's not an elegant way to solve the issue.

```
  $(".Button").click(function() {
  var timesRun = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      timesRun += 1;
      if(timesRun === 60){
          clearInterval(interval);
      }
      if ($(".gx-warning-message").text().length > 0) {
        toastrgx();
        $(".gx-warning-message").text('');
      }
  }, 200);
});
```

So, how can I make it better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be notified every time a GeneXus user event is fired, you can subscribe to `gx.onafterevent` event. For example:

```js
gx.fx.obs.addObserver('gx.onafterevent', scope, function () {
    // Here goes the code you want to execute 
    // every time a GeneXus event is fired
});
```

`scope` is the object you want to set as the `this` of the third parameter function.

Comment: sorry, come again? I don't really got the scope stuff, could u give an example?

Comment: `scope` is an object that will be set as the `this` object of the third parameter function. When programming a User Control you will probably want to set it to the User Control object, for example, inside the `show` function: gx.fx.obs.addObserver('gx.onafterevent', this, function () { .... });